# Scope of using statement

Tags: c#, using

I have a method that gives me a list of objects e.g.

```
public IEnumerable<Person> GetPerson()
{
    using (myEntities ctx = new myEntities())
    {
        return ctx.Person.Where(x => x.Age < 50);
    }
}
```

somewhere else i use this method

```
public void Main()
{
   var pList = GetPerson();
   pList = pList.Where(x => x.Age < 40);

   Person Item = pList.FirstOrDefault(); //materialization here
}
```

When i call `FirstOrDefault()` the select is being genereated and the data is being retrieved from the database.

Question: is the scope of `using (myEntities ctx = new myEntities())` reaching to the materialization?

On the one hand it schuld be because it manages the select/connection to the database and that is generated at materialization - on the other hand it's called outside of the method and that could be anywhere in the code - outside the using directives

Comment: I've edited the title of your question, as this is a using *statement*, not a using *directive*.

Comment: Did you try executing that code, does it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the `using` statement does not survive all the way out to your materialization of the query.

*Unless* calling `Person` already returns a fully materialized collection, which is unlikely and not typical.

What happens is the following:

1. You construct the context
2. You call the `Person` property of the context, and tuck on a LINQ query

   Likely this will return a deferred query, which has not yet executed
3. You dispose of the context
4. You return the LINQ query you constructed
5. You call `FirstOrDefault` on the query, attempting to execute it

At this point the likely result is that the code crashes because you're trying to execute a query using a context which has been disposed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to make the using work:

```
void Main()
{
    Person Item = UsingPerson(ps => ps.Where(x => x.Age < 40).Take(1)).FirstOrDefault();
}


public T[] UsingPerson<T>(Func<IQueryable<Person>, IQueryable<T>> project)
{
    using (myEntities ctx = new myEntities())
    {
        return project(ctx.Person.Where(x => x.Age < 50)).ToArray();
    }
}
```